# Javascript: preventing fake xhr requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Suppose you have an online game written in JavaScript and you want to store a global leaderboard in a database on the server side.

When the game ends, the JavaScript code has to send the score to the server. The question is, how do you prevent users from creating fake requests with fake scores?

What I thought of was encoding the score parameter in some way, so for instance instead of calling `/save_score?score=120`, do something like `/save_score?score=xD7ejc7hekgUDndowOSndhsy`. And then of course obfuscate the JavaScript code which does the encoding.

I realize this is not a fool proof solution. Given enough time, the attacker can still figure out how to encode the parameter.

Do you have any ideas for a better solution? Or at least some ideas on how to implement the parameter encoding to make it as hard as possible to figure out?

Comment: Anything that needs to be protected from tampering must be done on the server, not the client. The server should calculate the score, not require the client to send the score.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah but since the game is running on the client, the client would still need to send information to the server, so the server could calculate the score. So the attacker could just fake the requests with that information.

Comment: I work for a company that provides online bridge playing. The server knows which cards are in each player's hand, and will reject a message that says to play an invalid card. Your game has to be structured like this to prevent cheating.

Comment: The client should just send the user actions to the server, the server determines the result and how it affects the score. Note that this doesn't prevent a bot from emulating the user, but it does prevent it from faking the results.